# ayuda con carousel de ngx-bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, angular, carrusel

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web con Angular. Estoy intentando que funcione el carousel de ngx-bootstrap, específicamente el *Multilist Start From Index* que se encuentra en su [pagina](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel) pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Ya instalé jQuery, Bootstrap y ngx-bootstrap a través de npm e incluí los scripts y CSS en el angular.json pero cuando copio el código de la pagina me lo muestra como aparece en esta foto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si por ejemplo intento con el primer carousel de la pagina de ngx-bootsrtap me coloca las imágenes extremadamente grandes como se observa aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las imágenes son de resolución pequeña, no se qué es lo que está pasando sinceramente, ya he intentado de todo, hasta probé instalar todo nuevamente en una instalación limpia de Angular y todo sigue igual.

Aquí esta mi archivo angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "seapage": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/seapage",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css",
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "./node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js",
            ],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "seapage:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "seapage:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "seapage:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "seapage-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "seapage:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "seapage:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "seapage"
}
```

Y aquí el archivo app.module.ts donde importo el Carousel de ngx-bootstrap, tal cual como lo explican en su página:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SliderComponent } from './slider/slider.component';

import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SliderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CarouselModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Espero puedan ayudarme a resolver este problema, gracias de antemano. Saludos!